# What does metavar and action mean in argparse in Python?

Tags: python, action, argparse

I am reading through [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) module. I got stuck as what to metavar and action means

```
>>> parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
...                     help='an integer for the accumulator')
>>> parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
...                     const=sum, default=max,
...                     help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')
```

I might have missed but from what I read, I could not find definitions for `metavar` and 
`action (action="store_const", etc)`. what do they actually mean?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[metavar](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#metavar) is used in help messages in a place of an expected argument. See `FOO` is a default `metavar` here:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo')
>>> parser.add_argument('bar')
>>> parser.parse_args('X --foo Y'.split())
Namespace(bar='X', foo='Y')
>>> parser.print_help()
usage:  [-h] [--foo FOO] bar
...
```

[action](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#action) defines how to handle command-line arguments: store it as a constant, append into a list, store a boolean value etc. There are several built-in actions available, plus it's easy to write a custom one.

Comment: btw, what is the difference between these two?                            `parser.add_argument('cd_data', metavar='.dat', type = str, nargs='+')` and `parser.add_argument('-cd_data', metavar='.dat', type = str, nargs='+')`. There is only one change which `cd_data` to `-cd_data`

Comment: The one with `-` is an optional argument, see [docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags).

Comment: would you be able to look at this post and give your suggestion? `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19126399/why-args-add-argument-works-when-given-in-two-separate-statements-but-not-one-in`

Answer (score 80):

**Metavar:** It provides a different name for optional argument in help messages. Provide a value for the metavar keyword argument within `add_argument()`.

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', metavar='YYY')
>>> parser.add_argument('bar', metavar='XXX')
>>> parser.parse_args('X --foo Y'.split())
Namespace(bar='X', foo='Y')
>>> parser.print_help()
usage:  [-h] [--foo YYY] XXX

positional arguments:
  XXX

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  --foo YYY
```

Reference: http://www.usatlas.bnl.gov/~caballer/files/argparse/add_argument.html

**Action:**  Arguments can trigger different actions, specified by the action argument to `add_argument()`. There are six built-in actions that can be triggered when an argument is encountered:

1. `store`: Save the value, after optionally converting it to a different type. This is the default action taken if none is specified explicitly.
2. `store_true`/`store_false`: Save the appropriate boolean value.
3. `store_const`: Save a value defined as part of the argument specification, rather than a value that comes from the arguments being parsed. This is typically used to implement command line flags that aren’t booleans.
4. `append`: Save the value to a list. Multiple values are saved if the argument is repeated.
5. `append_const`: Save a value defined in the argument specification to a list.
6. `version`: Prints version details about the program and then exits.

Reference: http://bioportal.weizmann.ac.il/course/python/PyMOTW/PyMOTW/docs/argparse/index.html

Comment: I would add this: `store_true` means if true was specified then set param value but otherwise leave it to None. If `default` was also specified then param is set to that value instead of leaving it to None.

Comment: 7. `help`: Print the help and then exits.

Comment: Please, update two web links.