# why args.add_argument works when given in two separate statements but not one in python?

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to use argparse module to parse the arguments in command line.
here is the sample code

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('bar')
parser.add_argument('-foo')
args=parser.parse_args()
print args
```

running this

```
python argparsing.py "hello"
Namespace(bar='hello', foo=None)
```

however, this does not work

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('bar','--foo')
#parser.add_argument('-foo')
args=parser.parse_args()
print args
```

running this gives error

```
python argparsing.py "hello"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "argparsing.py", line 3, in <module>
    parser.add_argument('bar','-foo')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1267, in add_argument
    kwargs = self._get_optional_kwargs(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/argparse.py", line 1397, in _get_optional_kwargs
    raise ValueError(msg % tup)
ValueError: invalid option string 'bar': must start with a character '-'
```

The only difference between the two is I am adding argument separately (in two lines) in the first code but adding them in the same line as one statement in the failed code.
can someone help me understand this better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing the same thing. Look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_argument):

> name or flags - Either a name or a list of option strings, e.g. `foo` or `-f, --foo`.

You can't specify a list of positional arguments, just a single positional argument, or a list of option (flag) arguments. So, when you try to give it `'bar', '--foo'`, it tries to parse `'bar'` as an option, and it can't, because it doesn't start with a `-`.

And, as [the next section](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#name-or-flags) explains, when you give it a list of options, you're giving it a list of alternative names for *the same* flag, not a bunch of separate flags. So, you don't want to do what you're trying to do in the first place.

Comment: does that mean `parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo-bar', '--foo')', results in only flag in which `f, foo-bar and foo` are equivalent?

Comment: @user2708477: Yes. But you can try it and see for yourself just as easily as you can ask. If you `parse_args(['-fspam', '--foo=eggs'])`, or run the program with `python argparsing.py -fspam --foo=eggs`, you will get `Namespace(foo_bar='eggs')`.

Comment: @user2708477: Also, if you read the docs, it should be obvious that all of the flags given are going to end up with the same `action`, `dest`, etc. How else would it work? Plus… your example is character for character identical to one of the examples in the docs, under [dest](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#dest), which already _shows_ you what happens.

Comment: sorry, I am a bit confused. when I run this `python argparsing.py -fspam -f=eggs`, I get `Namespace(foo_bar='eggs')`. how could, `foo_bar = egg`, when I set `-f=eggs` in the commandline

Comment: @user2708477: Because `-f`, `--foo-bar`, and `--foo` are all the same option. If you don't supply a `dest` for that option: "`ArgumentParser` generates the value of dest by taking the first long option string and stripping away the initial `--` string." It's all explained in the docs that I linked for you. And the writing in the docs is much better than the writing in my comments.

Answer (score 3):

`add_argument` is meant to add a *single* argument. `'bar'` is one positional argument; `'--foo'` is one optional argument. You can't make an argument that is both positional and optional, hence the error.

If you want to define an argument, but name the option differently, use `dest`:

```
# accept an option --foo X, and store X into args.bar
parser.add_argument('--foo', dest='bar')
```

Note that you can define multiple aliases for a single optional argument, e.g.

```
parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo', '--frobnicate')
```

Comment: in the docs, multiple optional arguments are added eg `parser.add_argument('-f', '--foo-bar', '--foo')`.

Comment: @user2708477: all of those are aliases for an optional argument. You tried to define an argument that was simultaneously positional and optional.

Answer (score 0):

So you're giving `argparse` two totally different ways of defining an argument. So it's throwing an error because it can't understand your input

One method of defining an argument is using no dashes like you had first

```
parser.add_argument("bar")  # This is a required argument
```

Another is to use dashes

```
parser.add_argument("-f", "--foo")
```

`--foo` is just another way of specifying the same argument as `-f`. It is not a required argument like ones with no dashes (`bar`) unless you want it to be a required argument