# argparse: extraneous arguments for argument with no stored value?

Tags: python, argparse

Having a bit of problem with argparse in Python...

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument ("-o", "--optional", help="this is an optional argument")
args = parser.parse_args()

print ( args.optional )
```

Calling `test.py -h` will output...

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-o OPTIONAL]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -o OPTIONAL, --optional OPTIONAL
                        this is an optional argument
```

Is there any way I can get rid of the extra `OPTIONAL`s in the help menu? I know I could do this with `parser.add_argument ("-o", "--optional", help="this is an optional argument", action=store_true)`, except I can't because I need to call `args.optional` later on.

Again, this isn't so much about the functionality of the program as the aesthetics because `test.py -o hello` would print `hello`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to use a metavar parameter: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19124304/what-does-metavar-and-action-mean-in-argparse-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually an option with no arguments has an *action*, which will suppress that metavar:

```
parser.add_argument ("-o", "--optional", action='store_true')
```

Otherwise, you could amend the argument like this:

```
parser.add_argument ("-o", "--optional", metavar='', help="the help text")
```

Comment: I thought that's what you wanted.  Please add your desired output to the question.

Comment: sorry, I used double quotes instead of single which messed up the output. Using single quotes it executes properly. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First is this about the parsing of this argument or the display in the help?

```
parser.add_argument ("-o", "--optional", help="this is an optional argument")
```

has the default `store_true` action, and thus takes one argument.  As indicated in the usage:

```
usage: test.py [-h] [-o OPTIONAL]
```

where 'OPTIONAL' is a standin for the string that you will include after the `-o` or `--optional`.  And `args.optional` will have the value of that string.

`action='store_true` turns this argument into a boolean, False if not given, True if `-o` is provided.  It takes to no added value.

```
-o OPTIONAL, --optional OPTIONAL
```

is the normal way an Action like this is displayed in the help.  Again `OPTIONAL` is the place marker for the string that follows `-o` or `--optional`.  A `metavar` parameter can be used to customize that place marker.  It can be as short as "".

Some people don't like that repeated pattern, preferring something like

```
-o , --optional OPTIONAL
```

That has been discussed in previous questions. It requires a change to the `HelpFormatter` class (ie. a subclassing).

[python argparse help message, disable metavar for short options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23936145/python-argparse-help-message-disable-metavar-for-short-options)

Another thing is to simplify the definition

```
parser.add_argument ("-o", dest="optional", help="this is an optional argument")
```